# disable screen notification for incoming call

Tags: android, android-emulator

I manage to disable sound and viration for incoming phone calls and SMS.

i use BroadcastReceiver in order to catch incoming phone call, is it possible to disable screen notification during incoming call?

Thanks

Comment: I was also trying something similar. Could not find any public api to do it,if you get any solution please let me know.

Comment: I'm thinking about using PowerManager API in order to take screen off. take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
you can use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK